# Problems with SMB shares: Is it possible to downgrade gvfsd-smb?

Tags: 13.04, package-management, gvfs, smb

Since upgrading to Raring my work using SMB-shares has become painful. Access randomly hangs, processes stop etc. I believe I suffer from [this bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1075923)

My question is: can I downgrade gvfsd-smb? On Precise everything worked like a charm. I would gladly use that version of gvfsd-smb again.

Answer (score 1):

gvfs-smb Bug #1075923 Workaround:

downgrade gvfs-* to Version 1.12 of 12.10 with:
- `add /etc/apt/sources.list`

deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main

deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main

- run: `sudo apt-get update`
- install synaptic: `sudo apt-get install synaptic`
- run synaptic: `sudo synaptic`
- remove all gvfs-* nautilus with synaptic
- search gvfs-*, select, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> (Force Menu)
- select: gvfs-* Versions 1.12
- install by run install button
- search and install nautilus again.

Voila... Test Nautilus copy 1TB Files without freeze